# bash (sed/awk?) find line in file and print stuff 3 lines above?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to find a line in a txt file and then insert string 3 lines above the found line

Input:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

I want to look for "eee" and then print "WWW" 3 lines above it. Output:

```
aaa
WWW
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

I'm using awk and can only print "WWW" 1 line above "eee", and not 3:

```
awk '/eee/{print "WWW"} 4' file.txt
```

any ideas?

Comment: It is possible, but rather complicated. Can you explain why you need it? Perhaps there is better way of doing it, without needing to buffer output lines.

Comment: It's a quick fix to some text I'm processing.. I thought if I can insert one line above, shouldn't there be an easy way to insert 3 lines above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0;}/eee/{a[NR-3]="www\n" a[NR-3];}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i];}' file
```

Comment: this works, thanks!!! do you know how I can match multi line?? I tried: /eee\nfff/ but it doesn't work!